# Windows 8.1 Keep focus on TextBox

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

For a Windows Store App a requirement says : "Keep the focus on a TextBox when the page is loaded and after user interact with others components".

I solved the Issue when the page is loaded and when the user interact with other components in the same Grid (i.e. Buttons).

```
 MyTextBox.LostFocus += (s,e)=> {
     Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => SearchBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic));
 }
```

The problem is that when when the user interact with components in different view , like the AppBar.

Maybe i can solve the issue comparing the parent views and run the Focus(FocusState.Programmatic) if they are coming from the same view.

But... how ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to keep focus on TextBox. I do a simple demo and you can refer to this.

**XAML：**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Width="300" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarSeparator/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Like" Label="Like" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutUpdated += MainPage_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void MainPage_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        textbox1.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

I also find [one threads](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ffe73a6-7911-49a7-af82-88e99435cbcb/text-in-textbox-should-be-marked-as-default?forum=winappswithcsharp) you can refer to.